# Copy group calendar's events to specific list and, separate step, send email when item is added to group calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-list

i'm approching to SP and Flow for a few days.
I was added into an O365 group in which i found a shared calendar full of events.

What i want is:

1. copy all events into a list, loop the calendar events frequently (let's say daily or weekly) to check for new or modified items and update the entire list;
2. check daily for every new or modified events in the calendar (not in the list) and send email to referred team?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Hope someone help me.